# How to change the font of tabLayout with a custom font / calligraphy

Tags: java, android

I was looking for answers about how I can change the fonts of those tabs in that TabLayout to a custom font.

I tried this but it didnt work

```
 Typeface hero = Typeface.createFromAsset(getContext().getAssets(),"fonts/Hero Light.otf");

            textViewToConvert.setTypeface(hero);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Please explain what "it didnt work" means. Try removing the space from the filename. You might look at [other tab implementations](https://android-arsenal.com/tag/111?sort=created) that might offer built-in font configuration.

Answer (score 25):

**In your layout**

```
<android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
        android:id="@+id/sliding_tabs"
        style="@style/Tab"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="54dp"
        app:tabTextAppearance="@style/MineCustomTabText"/>
```

*and in your style folder*

```
<style name="MineCustomTabText" parent="TextAppearance.Design.Tab">
    <item name="android:textSize">12sp</item>
    <item name="android:textAllCaps">true</item>
    <item name="android:fontFamily">@font/two_light_1</item>
</style>
```

Answer (score 4):

We do it through styling. First define that text in tab has special style:

```
<android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
app:tabTextAppearance="@style/transactions__month_tabs_text_appearance">
```

And then in style define that you want to use custom font:

```
  <style name="transactions__month_tabs_text_appearance" parent="TextAppearance.Design.Tab">
    <item name="fontPath">fonts/your-font-name.ttf</item>
  </style>
```

BTW, we put all font names to string resources.

Comment: I'm sorry I'm new and really trying my best to learn new stuff. How would I go about specifying my font path in styles.xml?

Comment: Updated answer with just providing font name

Comment: it didn't work :/ 
`<style name="transactions__month_tabs_text_appearance" parent="TextAppearance.Design.Tab">
        <item name="fontPath">fonts/Gidole-Regular.otf</item>
    </style>`

Comment: heres my xml 
`<android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
            android:id="@+id/tabs"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:tag="tab_indicator_accent_color,bg_primary_color"
            app:tabIndicatorColor="@android:color/transparent"
            app:tabTextAppearance="@style/transactions__month_tabs_text_appearance"
            app:tabSelectedTextColor="@android:color/transparent" />`

Comment: yeah the font didnt change, i dont think i went wrong anywhere

Comment: Are fonts in `font` directory in `assets` folder? Is your activity has another text with custom font and it works?

Comment: yeah my font is is assets/fonts/...
My activity has other textViews where i have applied the custom font with calligraphy library

Comment: How did you apply font with caligraphy to view? Did you override `attachBaseContext()` method in activity?

Comment: yes i used attachbaseContext. Would that affect the outcome? It was my understanding that all the texts would get changed but the tabs didnt for some reason

Comment: Yes, that is correct.Then I don't know what might be the problem

Comment: I added that method to all the activities, but not the mainfragment class

Answer (score 2):

I am using this method in my project and works very well, its efficient in a way where I can customize tab fonts and bg color in future at different places in the app if I want.

```
public static void changeTabsFont(Context context, TabLayout tabLayout, int color) {

    ViewGroup vg = (ViewGroup) tabLayout.getChildAt(0);
    tabLayout.setBackgroundColor(color);
    int tabsCount = vg.getChildCount();
    for (int j = 0; j < tabsCount; j++) {
        ViewGroup vgTab = (ViewGroup) vg.getChildAt(j);
        int tabChildsCount = vgTab.getChildCount();
        for (int i = 0; i < tabChildsCount; i++) {
            View tabViewChild = vgTab.getChildAt(i);
            if (tabViewChild instanceof TextView) {
                ((TextView) tabViewChild).setTypeface(Typeface.createFromAsset(context.getAssets(), "Lato-Regular.ttf"));
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

you can use tabTextAppearance  in tablayout in Xml layout

Answer (score 1):

Create a TextView from Java Code or XML like this (Make sure to keep that id)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TextView
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:id="@android:id/text1"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:textSize="15sp"
android:textColor="@color/tabs_default_color"
android:gravity="center"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
/>
```

Then from code

```
for (int i = 0; i < tabLayout.getTabCount(); i++) {
    //R.layout is the previous defined xml
 TextView tv=(TextView)LayoutInflater.from(this).inflate(R.layout.custom_tab,null)
 tv.setTypeface(Typeface);       
 tabLayout.getTabAt(i).setCustomView(tv);

}
```

Comment: i saw this on another answer and tried it before but it didn't work too

Comment: It didn't crash, it just looks the same. the font didnt change

Comment: Are you sure the font you are applying isnt the same as the default one?

Comment: If you didnt change the id of the xml, there must be something wrong with the font, try a new one to see if it works

Comment: Okay i tried it again. now it says "layout inflator cannot be applied" i am doing this from a class called main fragment by the way.

Comment: Have you made the imports?