# typeface for tablayout title

Tags: java, android

Hello Everyone i'm working on a tabbed app .. How can i set custom typeface for tablayout titles in android? i want to use custom font for titles and i tried and searched but didn't find any way

my code thank you for helping.....!

MainActivity.java

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
            Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
            setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

            TabLayout tabLayout = (TabLayout) findViewById(R.id.tab_layout);
            tabLayout.addTab(tabLayout.newTab().setText("ONE"));
            tabLayout.addTab(tabLayout.newTab().setText("TWO"));
            tabLayout.addTab(tabLayout.newTab().setText("OTHER"));
            tabLayout.setTabGravity(TabLayout.GRAVITY_FILL);



            final ViewPager viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);
            final PagerAdapter adapter = new PagerAdapter
                    (getSupportFragmentManager(), tabLayout.getTabCount());
            viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);
            viewPager.addOnPageChangeListener(new TabLayout.TabLayoutOnPageChangeListener(tabLayout));
            tabLayout.setOnTabSelectedListener(new TabLayout.OnTabSelectedListener() {
                @Override
                public void onTabSelected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {
                    viewPager.setCurrentItem(tab.getPosition());
                }

                @Override
                public void onTabUnselected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {

                }

                @Override
                public void onTabReselected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {

                }
            });
        }
```

Comment: Specify style with font-family and use it with `app:tabTextAppearance` attribute in your `TabLayout`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to change the font of tabLayout with a custom font / calligraphy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45644607/how-to-change-the-font-of-tablayout-with-a-custom-font-calligraphy)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**In your layout**

```
<android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
        android:id="@+id/sliding_tabs"
        style="@style/Tab"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="54dp"
        app:tabTextAppearance="@style/MineCustomTabText"/>
```

**and in your style folder**

```
<style name="MineCustomTabText" parent="TextAppearance.Design.Tab">
    <item name="android:textSize">12sp</item>
    <item name="android:textAllCaps">true</item>
    <item name="android:fontFamily">@font/two_light_1</item>
</style>
```

Comment: can add font from assets ?

Comment: create directory assets - >fonts->calibri.ttf (here assets and fonts are folders and calibri.ttf is your font name) Check this :https://www.androidhive.info/2012/02/android-using-external-fonts/